# Can't use front camera in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I want to build front camera, but couldn't build front camera in Swift even I could build back camera.

When I only change "back" to "front", camera didn't work...

How can I use front camera?

```
var captureSesssion: AVCaptureSession!
var stillImageOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    captureSesssion = AVCaptureSession()
    stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    captureSesssion.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 

    captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .front) 
    //When change "front" to "back", camera is built.

    do {
       let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

       if (captureSesssion.canAddInput(input)) {
           captureSesssion.addInput(input)

           if (captureSesssion.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput)) {
               captureSesssion.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
               captureSesssion.startRunning() 

               previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSesssion)
               previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect 
               previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait 

               self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

               previewLayer?.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height / 2)
               previewLayer?.bounds = self.view.frame
           }
       }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: does your test device's selfie camera work on the camera app?

Comment: Yes, I use iPhone SE and can use front camera on the camera app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The front camera for iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus can record 1080p but on older models it can only record 720p. Thus, you just need to change the session preset, i.e.:

```
captureSesssion.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720
```

**Swift 4:**

```
captureSesssion.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1280x720
```